# what is 'application/x-httpd-php' in apache confiquration?

Tags: php, apache

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php.php

PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

I am not able to understand the above lines. Please anyone give me a deep explanation?

Comment: check out https://serverfault.com/questions/180104/what-is-addtype-application-x-httpd-php-source